# SQL server with C# - Fixing nvarchar(50) to fit listview display

Tags: c#, string

I use an SQL database, and I query it for data. some of my fields are of type nvarcar(50). therefore, when I populate them in a listview, i get annoying three dots (...) 
e.g: [China ...]
How can I get rid of it?

I am a new user so i can't upload image, sorry.

Comment: The three dots in the ListView are created by the listview control, not by the database.

Comment: I think, you must set the size of the ListView column to appropriate size.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i think there was a slight misunderstanding: I meant that my text itself is short (e.g China) but the size of the string is 50 (because of the nvarchar(50). I wish to make it shorter...

Comment: Are you saying your string is padded with elipsis coming *from* the database?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to autosize the column using `AutoResizeColumn()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.autoresizecolumn(v=vs.90).aspx

I assumed winform since you didn't specify.